# Search for a string in related tables

Tags: sql

I have a database with several tables, one being used to reference others :

Main table :

```
MAIN | table1 | table2 | table3
        int   |  int   |  int
```

Each line of this table corresponds to a product, and contains the oid of a line in a daughter table

Then I have my daughter tables :

```
TABLE1 | name | adress | phone
       | text | text   | ...
```

My question is quite simple, even though as I just start using databases I can't get to find the answer.

I would like to get the oid(s) of the line(s) of the main table which references the line of table1 for which name is equals to "bob".

Something like :

```
SELECT * from main where table1.name = "bob"
```

If no complete solution, could you point me to some documentation ? 
I think I miss vocabulary to find proper ressurces to do that.

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like `SELECT oid FROM MAIN WHERE table1 IN (SELECT oid FROM TABLE1 WHERE name = 'bob')`?

`table1` == foreign key from `MAIN` to `TABLE1`.

Comment: I take this one as solution, but it is completely depending on my context. I have oid coolumns in each of my tables, and I have to use SELECT columns FROM . . . instead of SELECT * in my framework . This leads to ambiguous error.

Answer (score 2):

assuming the oid is a column in table 1 as well as in the main table:

```
SELECT m.oid
FROM main m
INNER JOIN table1 t
ON m.table1 = t.oid
WHERE t.name = 'bob'
```

Comment: And now let us proceed to [Nested queries vs. joins](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3380918/1028230) ;)  If you want any fields from TABLE1, this is a better answer. I may have interpreted the question too literally.

Comment: And in which case would your answer be better ruffin ? Actually, I need all elements so my query will be a select * from

Comment: My answer is, at best (depending on your dbms' query compilation), only "as good". I think it's more specifically targeted to answering "I would like to *get the oid(s)* of the line(s) of the main table...". Otherwise, it's useful "only" as a second way to solve this sort of problem. (ie, gabtub clearly gets the check in your situation) Cheers!