# Find business days in a month using sql

Tags: sql

I am using java udf to exclude sat and sun to get business days.I am stuck with sql query to exclude holidays which are in another table called holidays.Please some one help me.
I have two tables which are as follows:
table1
trade_date
12-02-2013
14-02-2013
02-03-2013
25-04-2013
table2
holidays
11-02-2013
13-02-2013
02-03-2013
20-04-2013

And my output should be as follows:
trade_date  business_day
12-02-2013    7
14-02-2013    8
02-03-2013    0(because it is saturday)
25-04-2013    18

I tried this query:

```
select d.t_date 
from dates d 
left outer join holidays h on (d.t_date = h.h_date)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to exclude them using an `in` clause:

```
select d.t_date 
from dates d 
where d.t_date not in (select h.h_date from holidays)
```

If that doesn't work for you, just modify the current query a little:

```
select d.t_date 
from dates d 
left outer join holidays h on (d.t_date = h.h_date)
where h.h_date is null
```

This says that if there **is not a match** in the `holidays` table the record can be included.

Comment: The second query is much faster and should work. First one is slow.

Comment: @meewoK, I don't think you can make that statement just as a blanket. A simple index on `h_date` makes the sub query excessively fast. And keep in mind that `holidays` is going to be a pretty small table so it's a very **simple** exclusion for the primary query.

Comment: OK correction, the second query is faster than the first and will get increasingly fast as the dataset increases :). For the sake of optimization I have to point that out. The first query executes `select h.h_date from holidays` for EVERY row of dates. The seconds one simply performs a left outer join and checks for null - much cheaper. If you run both queries for a time range over 10 years, I'm sure it will make a difference.

Comment: @meewoK, are you 100% sure on the execution plan of that first one? That doesn't actually make sense. **I believe** the actual execution plan would be, get all rows from the `dates` table and then remove those that aren't in the cached array retrieved from the sub query. I could be wrong, but that execution plan just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The execution plan is affected by optimziations. I believe the second SQL statement is based on quicker logic/operations, but I can't know what optimizations will occur within the CTE. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3380918/1688441

Comment: Have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0f9e5/2 , check MS and execution times. It seems that the correlated subquery is a bit slower.

Comment: @basu, what's wrong with the answer I provided? Have you tried it? If so, what's the outcome? Be more specific, because we did try and help you.